# 58=(243): Market orders not accepted at this time

Tags: fix-protocol

I am sending the Market Request on the FIX server as:

**Request:**
FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, outgoing> (8=FIXT.1.1|9=173|35=D|34=43|49=135|52=20200213-06:30:47.204|56=PSE|1=11011000000035|11=1581575447212|38=1000|**40=1**|54=1|55=PIZZA|59=0|60=20200213-14:30:47.204|453=1|448=13501100|447=C|452=12|10=048|)

In the request I am sending the 40 tag i.e(Order Type)=1 and had recieved the following response with the error as:

**Response:**
FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, incoming> (8=FIXT.1.1|9=000353|35=8|49=PSE|56=135|34=43|57=13501100|52=20200213-06:30:47.318|37=NONE|11=1581575447212|453=4|448=13501999|447=C|452=11|448=13501999|447=C|452=36|448=13501100|447=C|452=12|448=135|447=C|452=1|17=1808|150=8|39=8|103=99|1=11011000000035|55=PIZZA|54=1|38=1000|59=0|528=A|151=0|14=0|60=20200213-06:30:47.116|**58=(243):** **Market orders not accepted at this time**|10=101|)

The request is send according to the documentary of the FIX server, so please let me know what changes should be made in the request for getting the proper response??

Comment: You should ask PSE when Orders can be sent. Obviously this is not possible at the time you tried. Do other order types work?

Comment: But I had placed the Limit Order at the same time when the Market order  was placed and it was successfully placed,  then why there is problem in the Market Order??

Comment: I don't know. Ask PSE